# How to replace a substring without using replace() methods

Tags: java, string, replace

I am trying to convert a text document to shorthand, without using any of the replace() methods in java. One of the strings I am converting is "the" to "&". The problem is, that I do not know the substring of each word that contains the "the" string. So how do I replace that part of a string without using the replace() method?

Ex: "their" would become "&ir", "together" would become "toge&r"

This is what I have started with,

```
String the = "the";
Scanner wordScanner = new Scanner(word);
    if (wordScanner.contains(the)) {
        the = "&";
    }
```

I am just not sure how to go about the replacement.

Comment: Having a variable named `the` and assign it with "the" is weird.

Comment: Use `String.split(the)`, and then concatenate all the words using `&`.

Comment: Why do you not want to use .replace(...)?  This is kind of what it was designed to do.

Comment: Then use `replaceAll` :)

Comment: @Pherion: Most likely because this is an assignment?

Comment: I mean you could use string.split on "the" and then use a string builder to append different strings but it is just a pain compared to String.Replace()

Answer (score 0):

You could try this :

```
String word = "your string with the";
word = StringUtils.join(word.split("the"),"&");
Scanner wordScanner = new Scanner(word);
```

Comment: How is this replacing the word from the Scanner? This works great for changing `the` but does nothing to change `wordScanner`

Comment: What if you have `there`? The regex will match it as well. At the least, I think that the expression should be `\bthe\b`.

Comment: just edited the answer.
@npinti this is what is needed, see the Ex. of the question

Answer (score 0):

I do not get your usage of `Scanner` for this, but you can read each character into a buffer (`StringBuilder`) until you read "the" into the buffer.  Once you've done that, you can delete the word and then append the word you want to replace with.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String data = "their together the them forever";
    String wordToReplace = "the";
    String wordToReplaceWith = "&";

    Scanner wordScanner = new Scanner(data);
    // Using this delimiter to get one character at a time from the scanner
    wordScanner.useDelimiter("");

    StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
    while (wordScanner.hasNext()) {
        buffer.append(wordScanner.next());

        // Check if the word you want to replace is in the buffer
        int wordToReplaceIndex = buffer.indexOf(wordToReplace);
        if (wordToReplaceIndex > -1) {
            // Delete the word you don't want in the buffer
            buffer.delete(wordToReplaceIndex, wordToReplaceIndex + wordToReplace.length());
            // Append the word to replace the deleted word with
            buffer.append(wordToReplaceWith);
        } 
    }

    // Output results
    System.out.println(buffer);
}
```

Results:

```
&ir toge&r & &m forever
```

This can be done without a Scanner using just a `while` loop and `StringBuilder`

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String data = "their together the them forever";
    StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder(data);

    String wordToReplace = "the";
    String wordToReplaceWith = "&";

    int wordToReplaceIndex = -1;
    while ((wordToReplaceIndex = buffer.indexOf(wordToReplace)) > -1) {
        buffer.delete(wordToReplaceIndex, wordToReplaceIndex + wordToReplace.length());
        buffer.insert(wordToReplaceIndex, wordToReplaceWith);
    }

    System.out.println(buffer);
}
```

Results:

```
&ir toge&r & &m forever
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Pattern and Matcher Regex:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("the ");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("the cat and their owners");
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        while(matcher.find()){
            matcher.appendReplacement(sb, "& ");
        }
        matcher.appendTail(sb);
        System.out.println(sb.toString());
```